# Retrieve data from two tables but exclude certain data

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables, consider the following.

### Articles

```
ART_ID
ART_NAME
```

### Transaction

```
TRA_ID
ART_ID (FK)
TRA_STATUS
```

I need data available in both `Articles` & `Transaction` but for data coming from `Transaction` the `TRA_STATUS` should be equal to 'A'

Here is the query that I have already tried

```
SELECT  ART_NAME 
FROM Articles
INNER JOIN Transaction ON Transaction.ART_ID = Articles.ART_ID
WHERE TRA_STATUS='A'
```

I have already tried an outter join to get data from both tables but I can't seem to have the last filter where TRA_STATUS should equal to 'A', if I just add a where condition it will remove data from Articles as well.

Comment: Please show the query that you have tried (by editing your question).

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited.. please check

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to see all rows from articles, but only matching rows from Transaction.

If that's the case, the filter needs to be a *condition of the join*:

```
SELECT  
  a.ART_ID, 
  a.ART_NAME,
  t.TRA_ID,
  t.TRA_STATUS 
FROM 
  Articles a
LEFT JOIN Transaction t ON t.ART_ID = a.ART_ID AND t.TRA_STATUS LIKE 'A'
```

If you filter in the WHERE clause, the LEFT JOIN effectively becomes an INNER JOIN.

Comment: This query still leaves records from Transaction table which do not match TRA_STATUS equals 'A'.

Comment: Not exactly.  If there is a matching row in transaction, it will be returned.  If there is no matching row, the transaction table values will return as null.

Comment: you are right..! but is there a way to exclude that row altogether if TRA_STATUS = 'A'

Comment: I assume you mean if TRA_STATUS != 'A'?  Yes, you can exclude those rows, but that's an inner join, and now you lose the unmatched rows in the Articles table (basically your original query).

Comment: I am not restricting myself to a certain join, any form of join would be fine if it produces the right result. And I don't wont unmatched records between the table to disappear so that takes inner join as not a possible solution. Any help is greatly appreciated as I can't seem to work this out myself, tried different things for hours now..!

Comment: You've now said you both want to include the row and exclude the row.  Which is it?  Edit your question to include some sample data and the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Articles.ART_ID, ART_NAME,TRA_ID,TRA_STATUS 
FROM Articles
INNER JOIN `Transaction` ON `Transaction`.ART_ID = Articles.ART_ID
WHERE TRA_STATUS = 'A';
```

Transaction is a **reserved** word. Rename the table or make sure you don't mess up with it by using `.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Articles
INNER JOIN Transaction ON Articles.ART_ID = Transaction.ART_ID
WHERE Transaction.TRA_STATUS = 'A'
```

Comment: Though your answer might me good, adding some additional info won't harm. You might explain why you think your method works and what it differs from the OP's initial try, for instance.